# Citing paragraphs with multiple references

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am using MLA. I have two paragraphs which are paraphrases of 5 different papers over tillage. Each fact and statement in the two paragraphs are somehow (pretty directly) stated in each of those papers. All my references are used in those two paragraphs as everything else is a proposed solution that hasn't been test and all other information is *cogni scienti*. Do I just stick the citations at the end of the two paragraphs? I want to use all these references to show consensus in the agricultural science community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all five papers contain the same factual information, then you could do the following:

> Smith says there are eight planets (13). Doe concurs (57), as do Johnson (910), Azikiwe (219) and Kim (43).

If you there are multiple small facts spread throughout their papers, you can probably get away without page numbers for all but the first:

> Smith says there are eight planets (13). She also indicates that Mercury is the closest, but not the hottest — that's Venus (19). Furthermore, she states that the asteroid belt is between Mars and Jupiter (22). This information is generally agreed upon by the astronomical community, and is repeated in articles by Doe, Johnson, Azikiwe, and Kim.

If any of those authors have multiple works in your works cited (remember, all of them should be in your works cited with the relevant article/chapter pages included), then for those authors you would put the name of the particular one you're referencing either in parentheses or explicitly referenced:

> Smith says there are eight planets (13). She also indicates that Mercury is the closest, but not the hottest — that's Venus (19). Furthermore, she states that the asteroid belt is between Mars and Jupiter (22). This information is generally agreed upon by the astronomical community, and is repeated by Doe, Johnson, Azikiwe (*Our Solar System*), and Kim's "A Summary of Planetary Statistics".

(You wouldn't want to mix both of the reference styles and you'd probably prefer *by [an author]* and *in [something by the author]* , but the last example is more for illustration than pretty wording.)